# Why can't I call cmake install like in the docs?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to port a package to ROS2 using ament cmake hooks based on https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Tutorials/Ament-CMake-Documentation/#building-a-library

When I do something like the recommendation for target-based installs, I get an error about an unknown mode.

So is there a typo in that documentation?
Also, when would I want a target-based install and when would I want a non-target-based install?

Cmake Fragment:

```
install(
  sba
  TARGETS sba
  EXPORT export_sba
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)
```

Error message

```
--- stderr: sparse_bundle_adjustment
CMake Error at /opt/ros/dashing/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/symlink_install/install.cmake:43 (_install):
  _install called with unknown mode SBA
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:35 (install)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330905/why-can%27t-i-call-cmake-install-like-in-the-docs?/) by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2019-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The CMake function `install()` doesn't have a signature where the first argument is `sba`. The documentation enumerates a set of signatures - for each the first argument is a known keyword like `TARGETS`, `DIRECTORY`, etc. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html

The specific example in the documentation is certainly wrong. I would guess the first argument just needs to be removed.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-08-16**:
The docs should be fixed by https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/pull/318